# How to properly dispose of a pthread mutex?

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex

I wrote a class to wrap a mutex. In the destructor, I call pthread_mutex_destroy and sometimes it returns EBUSY because some other thread has not released it. My question is, what is the best way to handle the destruction of a mutex? Should I wait for it to be free?

Here is what I have so far, which may not be the best solution:

```
Mutex::~Mutex()
{
    int rc = pthread_mutex_destroy( &_mutex );
    while ( rc == EBUSY )
    {
        lock(); // Call to pthread_mutex_lock
        unlock(); // Call to pthread_mutex_unlock

        // Attempt destroy again
        rc = pthread_mutex_destroy( &_mutex );
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, in C++11, you may use directly `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard`.

Comment: FWIW, std::mutex::~mutex() behavior is undefined if the mutex is currently owned.  I would assert/bugcheck loudly in this scenario, and figure out how you ended up in such a state

Comment: @Bukes `EBUSY` is well defined and documented behaviour of `pthread_mutex_destroy`.

Comment: @Maxim - Yes it is.  My point was that the destructor for the standard library implementation indicates undefined behavior for scenarios where the resource is destroyed while it's in use (locked,or being waited on) - which is apparently what is happening in the OPs code.  Attempting to recover from this is likely to mask bugs, which is why I recommended asserting/bugchecking/logging in his destructor when pthread_mutex_destroy() returns EBUSY....

Comment: @Bukes I see your point now and agree with you that `EBUSY` from `pthread_mutex_destroy` indicates a programming error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, what is the best way to handle the destruction of a mutex? Should I wait for it to be free?

You should not destroy resources while they are being used because that often leads to undefined behaviour.

The correct course of action is:

- Tell the other thread to release the resources and wait till it does, or
- Tell the other thread to terminate politely an wait till it has done so, or
- Pass the ownership of the resource to another thread and let it manage the resource's lifetime as it pleases, or
- Use shared resources, so that they stay alive while its users are still around.